# Rewrite to hide default doc in IIS 8

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a site that uses index.cfm for the default page of the whole site. Varibles are passed in the url as value pars seperated by forward slashes.

Example:

```
www.domain.com/index.cfm/show_register/memberType_Buyer/membershipLevel_Vip
www.domain.com/index.cfm/show_register/memberType_seller/membershipLevel_Standard
www.domain.com/index.cfm/show_items/category_bike/id_123
```

I would like to "hide" index.cfm in the url but have it still work.

I have tried using a many different rules I have found (the latest being)

```
<rewrite>
    <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)index.cfm" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^.*(index.cfm/).*$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

But I can't seem to get it to work correctly.  I feel like since index.cfm is the default document for the site I might be in some kind of infinite loop.

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I have rewrite installed.
[image]

This is what the I am seeing in IIS
[image]

This is what the browser is displaying
[image]

I did get this rewrite to work but now it is adding "index.cfm" to everything include files like `/js/global.js` and `/css/site.css`

```
        <rules>
            <rule name="Default Document">
                <match url="\/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

So although I am getting closer I am not quite there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rewrite rule will do that for you:

```
<rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/index.cfm" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

It will **rewrite** requests:

`www.domain.com/show_register/memberType_Buyer/membershipLevel_Vip` to `www.domain.com/index.cfm/show_register/memberType_Buyer/membershipLevel_Vip`

Comment: I tried this but get `"
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
"` and if I try to pull the site rewrite up in IIS I get "Error performing opperation" with the web.config path

Comment: Probably yo udidnt install URL rewrite module. Please try to install this: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I did install it. I added some screen shots to the question so you can get a better picture of what I am seeing.

Comment: @Lance i've edited my answer, not it's ignoring css and js files. Should work for you